# What is the smallest 4-chromatic graph of girth 5?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings

It is known that the smallest 4-chromatic graph of girth 4 is the [Grötzsch graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) (11 vertices). What happens for girth 5?

The [Brinkmann graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brinkmann_graph) (21 vertices) has chromatic number 4, girth 5 and is 4-regular. Moreover it is the smallest graph (in terms of the order) with these three properties.

Dropping the 4-regularity constraint, is there a graph of smaller order than the Brinkmann graph that is 4-chromatic and of girth 5? I haven't found anything in the literature but I may have missed it.

Comment: It is on at least 15 vertices.

Comment: @joro can you give more details?

Comment: I did computer search in sage. Let me know if you need the code to run it longer if you wish (I gave up in about 15 minutes).

Comment: Sure, please send it.

Comment: OK, just to add some comments...

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/jor0/e2402a8dfb3a210dc88d#file-mogirth5-sage Probably comment the suggested printing for speed.

Comment: No problem. I fixed a bug if you comment the line and made it slightly better. Suggest to use the latest version.

Comment: Aren't there bounds for $\delta,\Delta$? This might significantly speed to program.

Comment: Yes, good idea: we can assume that $\Delta\geq 4$ (Brook's theorem). Also, if we look for a minimal graph, we can assume that $\delta\geq 3$ (otherwise, removing a degree 2-vertex, if the resulting graph is 3-colorable we could extend the 3-coloring, a contradiction. Hence the smaller graph is also 4-chromatic).

Comment: Hm, is there a rough UPPER bound for $\Delta$?

Comment: Assuming $n\leq 20$, take a vertex of max. degree. Its second neighborhood must contain an odd cycle (otherwise we can give a 3-coloring). Therefore it has at least 5 vertices, and $\Delta\leq 14$.

Comment: If you assume $\delta \ge 3$, in the line with "-t -f" add " -d3". This will generate graphs with the assumption, killing some trees.

Comment: Assuming $\delta \ge 3$ it is on at least 18 vertices. With this assumption a _very wild guess_ for the running time is at most several days.

Comment: Since $\delta\geq 3$, we may estimate $\Delta$ better. Take any vertex of degree $\Delta$; all its $\Delta$ neighbors, as well as their $\geq (\delta-1)\Delta$ other neighbors are distinct (due to the girth condition), so there are at least $1+\Delta\delta$ vertices at all. Thus, if $\Delta\geq 7$ then there are at least 22 vertices, and we may assume $\Delta\leq 6$.

Comment: IlyaBogdanov's suggestion $\Delta \le 6$ means the program should be modified with " -d3 -D6"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My computer tells me that there 195291625 graphs on 20 vertices with minimum degree at least 3 and maximum degree at most 6 and girth at least 5.

Sadly none of them have chromatic number 4, I just get 48 bipartite ones and the remainder being 3-chromatic.

Independent verification would be useful.

**Added** Here's a 21-vertex graph that is not the Brinkmann graph, but is 4-chromatic and has girth equal to 5, also in graph6 format for direct input to Sage. It has the same number of edges as a 4-regular graph but has two vertices of degree 3 and two of degree 5. I bet that it is obtained from the Brinkmann graph by some small edge-swap move.

```
g = Graph("T???C@?K@OA_A_b?AWAQ_?kPCGc`OFCG?da?")

Graph 1, order 21.
  0 : 7 13 18 19;
  1 : 8 15 17 19;
  2 : 9 10 19 20;
  3 : 9 11 14 18;
  4 : 10 12 13 15;
  5 : 11 13 17 20;
  6 : 12 14 16 19;
  7 : 0 14 15 20;
  8 : 1 16 18 20;
  9 : 2 3 15 16;
 10 : 2 4 17 18;
 11 : 3 5 19;
 12 : 4 6 20;
 13 : 0 4 5 16;
 14 : 3 6 7 17;
 15 : 1 4 7 9;
 16 : 6 8 9 13;
 17 : 1 5 10 14;
 18 : 0 3 8 10;
 19 : 0 1 2 6 11;
 20 : 2 5 7 8 12;
```

**More added**

There are smaller 4-chromatic girth-5 graphs than Brinkmann's graph, because some of the examples that are appearing have fewer *edges* even though they have the same number of vertices. The search is about 10% complete and there are 7 graphs found so far.

The prettiest one has just 40 edges and an automorphism group of order 5 consisting of a single fixed point and 4 5-cycles (which is vaguely reminiscent of Mycielski's construction).

**Final Addition**

After a little over 31 hours on the same multi-core machine, the computation of the full list of graphs with minimum degree at least 3, maximum degree at most 6 and girth at least 5 terminated.

Of the 5006797077 graphs constructed, just 18 had chromatic number 4 and therefore have an equal claim to being the smallest 4-chromatic graphs of girth 5 (at least in terms of counting vertices).

Among these graphs, 1 has 40 edges, 3 have 41, 12 have 42 and 2 have 43 edges.  One is the 4-regular Brinkmann graph. The automorphism groups have orders 14 (Brinkmann graph), 5 (the element of order 5 has one fixed point and 4 x 5-cycles), 2 (8 times) and 1 (8 times). Some of the graphs are obtained from the others by adding/deleting an edge, but mostly not.

For those interested, the graphs (in graph6 format) are as follows:

```
T???C@?K@OA_A_b?AWAQ_?kPCGc`OFCG?da?
T???C@?GC_B?@_p?@W@cADS@`CCDg@HP@GY?
T???C@?GC_B?@_p??T@cAOp?Po@Y@AOsA_e?
T???C@?GC_B?@_p??T@cAAE_SoAEgD@K?l?_
T???C@?GC_B?@_p??T@cAAE_So@Q@AEGA_e?
T???C@?GC_B?@_p??T@cAAE_So@Q@AEgA_e?
T???C@?GC_B?@_b?@WAIGCWaac?HpBOS@QP?
T????A?OD?B?P_[?Ac@W?@F?I`@BKAQPAROO
T????A?O@?Q?F?S_HC@S?HGQGWFAC?b__FK_
T???C@?g?o?os?PCKP?d_AoOpCCPG@WC?Dg?
T???C@?G?oA_A__`IGB?QH?jK?C`c@RG?FW?
T???C@?GC_@_E_QOOS?M?CX?s@_PobCWBCQ?
T????A?O@_@_g_Y?BC?H_CD_R@QDWCQo@DA_
T???C@?G?_P?R?IOOa?i?SDAqAACR?T__ck?
T????A?O@?Q?R?[?BO@P?AF?E`?bSAEGadO_
T????A?O@?Q?R?[?BO@P?AF?E`GbSAEGadO_
T????A?WA_D?@_`CGSCc?@J?JH?pcEAK?t?_
T???C@?GC_H?@_T??[BCOAIac_CSa@aK?C[_
```

Comment: Did you use nauty for graph generation? How long the generation took?

Comment: 1000 small processes, each of the form geng -t -f -d3 -D6 20 x/1000 (where x ranges from 0..999) run in parallel on a machine with 2 cpus, each with 6 cores, each with 2 threads. Total elapsed time was about 2 hours.

Comment: So 21 is the answer then? Is the Brinkman graph the unique 4-chromatic graph of girth 5 and order 21?

Comment: @verret Assuming correctness of computations the answer is 21.

Comment: @joro My meta-algorithm for all graph isomorphism or computation problems is: (1) Check whether any program in the nauty package (nauty, Traces, geng, genbg, plantri, etc) does exactly what I want, (2) Check whether I can write a plug-in to any of the above that does what I want, (3) Ask Brendan if he's got a non-distributed program that does what I want, (4) Write the damn thing myself.

Comment: @verret Not quite... assuming correctness there is no 20-vertex example, however there could be a different 21-vertex example. Of course if I change 20 to 21 in the above then I can find them all in a day or two. And yes, it is already running.

Comment: Sound meta-algorithm. Would you please verify my computation for orders less than 20? (I assumed the graphs are connected). Up to 18 it is fast on a single thread.

Comment: @GordonRoyle, I guess this answers my question (assuming the computations are correct). And teaches us how to use geng efficiently :-) It would be nice if you can also post the nice examples of order 21 you are finding!

Comment: So, I suppose the one of size 40 can be declared the smallest! Next question: what about girth 6? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer based on computer search.

There is no smaller solution with $\delta \ge 4$.

According to comments, smaller graph must satisfy
$\delta \ge 3, \Delta \le 6$.

If it is exists, it is on $20$ vertices.

Link to sage implementation is in the comments.

Comment: I'm running the program, it has n't found any with 19 vertices.

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud I suppose you applied the patch "-d3 -D6"? Did you finish all of order 19?

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud I finished order 19, no solutions.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant too in my earlier comment.